# Access a Control.Property inside a UserControl from Parent Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to get an `Ellipse` to blink in case the icon inside another `UserControl` is Pause, and stop blinking if the icon is Play.

Here is the Ellipse and my attempt at binding to the `PlayIcon.Opacity` with a `DataTrigger`, which isn't working

```
<Ellipse.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Opacity, Path=PlayIcon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type views:PlayButton}}}" Value="0">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation 
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="0"
                                 To="3"
                                 RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                 AutoReverse="True"
                                 Duration="0:0:0.1"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Ellipse.Style>

<views:PlayButton />
```

Here is the Pause and Play Icons in the `PlayButton` UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyNamespace.PlayButton" ...>
    ...
    <Path Name="PlayIcon" Fill="Blue" Opacity="0" Data="M18,12 18,38 35,25"/>
    <Path Name="PauseIcon" Fill="Blue" Opacity="10"  Data="M15,12 15,38 23,38 23,12z M27,12 27,38 35,38 35,12" />
    ...
</UserControl>
```

How can I make this DataTrigger fire when the Opacity of the Play Icon is 0, or if Pause icon Opacity is 10 inside the `PlayButton` UserControl?

Comment: Opacity can be set between 0 to 1 only ...500 is not possible......like 0.1 ,0.2,0.3,0.4 ets.

Comment: I am just trying to match to a value...500 or 10 doesn't make any difference....However I will edit it...

Comment: Why are you unable to get the bindings? Do you get any exceptions? Do you get any binding errors in the output window? BTW, you have shown your PlayIcon as a `<Path>` but your trigger says `x:Type views:PlayButton`. Is that correct? your binding seems to be incorrect as well, because you have defined `Path` twice, first one is `Opacity` and the second one is `PlayIcon`. Does that even compile?

Comment: First Of all - there are no errors, but I do not get the expected behavior - The animation doesn't happen. Secondly I tried to explore possible ways to bind it and found the relative source solution but it seems I have not got it right. Please let me know the changes I have to make for it to work.

Comment: Is both your `PlayIcon` and your `Ellipse` inside your `<views:PlayButton>` UserControl? Your question makes it sound like your `Ellipse` is outside of the `UserControl`, in which case you probably need a custom `DependencyProperty` on `PlayButton` that you can use in your bindings for both `PlayIcon.Opacity` and `Ellipse.DataTrigger`.

Comment: if you want to get the opacity from the node `<Path Name="PlayIcon" ..>` you shouldn't set the relative source to a type of PlayButton. I am having issues understanding your requirements. What property do you want to bind to the ellipse style? the playbutton.opacity or the path.opacity?

Comment: Also @Default is correct and you are binding the `Path` property of your `Ellipse.DataTrigger` binding twice, which I'm surprised even compiles. If you don't specify a property name in the binding, it assume's its the `Path` property, so you have the `Path` property of the binding bound to both the `Opacity` and `PlayIcon` properties of `PlayButton` (and I suspect `PlayIcon` is not a publicly visible property)

Comment: @Rachel Thank you for the reply....Yes the ellipse is not part of the user control. I see the mistake in binding, but is thr a way for me to access the play and pause icons directly in binding instead of using Dependency property?

Comment: @Default I want to bind the path.opacity value in ellipse

Comment: @DRN You could probably make your `PlayIcon` control `public` inside your `UserControl`, so that binding to `somePlayButton.PlayIcon.Opacity` is a valid path, however I'm not positive if the `Opacity` property raises change notifications for the binding to update or not. Personally I think a cleaner solution would be to use a `DependencyProperty` for something like this, however use whatever works best for you and your scenario :)